# Python getting xml same childnodes in same line

Tags: python, xml

### I have a xml file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SetupConf>
  <LocSetup>
    <Src>
      <Dir>C:\User1\test1</Dir>
      <Dir>C:\User2\log</Dir>
      <Dir>D:\Users\Checkup</Dir>
      <Dir>D:\Work1</Dir>
      <Dir>E:\job1</Dir>
     </Src>
  </LocSetup>
  </SetupConf>
```

---

where `<Dir>` node depends on user input. In "Dir" node it may be 1,2,5,10 dir structure defined.
I am able to extract data from the xml using below Python code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom = minidom.parse('Test0001.xml')
Src=dom.getElementsByTagName('Src')

for node in Src:
    alist =node.getElementsByTagName('Dir')
    for a in alist:
        dirtext = a.childNodes[0].nodeValue + ','
        print dirtext
```

...............
I am getting Output in multi line as:

```
C:\User1\test1,
C:\User2\log,
D:\Users\Checkup,
D:\Work1,
E:\job1,
```

---

But I need the output in single line without space and remove last comma, like:

```
 C:\User1\test1,C:\User2\log,D:\Users\Checkup,D:\Work1,E:\job1
```

Please help me in this regard, I have tried a lot... It may be by using itertools grouping or defaultdict. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are trying to store the string so use *str.join*:

```
output = ",".join([a.childNodes[0].nodeValue for node in Src for a in node.getElementsByTagName('Dir')])
```

You could add a trailing comma after the print so you don't get a newline printed after each`print dirte,` but that won't account for the trailing comma and does not help you if you actually want to store the string.

Output:

```
In [1]: from xml.dom import minidom

In [2]: x = r"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ...:   <SetupConf>
   ...:   <LocSetup>
   ...:     <Src>
   ...:       <Dir>C:\User1\test1</Dir>
   ...:       <Dir>C:\User2\log</Dir>
   ...:       <Dir>D:\Users\Checkup</Dir>
   ...:       <Dir>D:\Work1</Dir>
   ...:       <Dir>E:\job1</Dir>
   ...:      </Src>
   ...:   </LocSetup>
   ...:   </SetupConf>"""

In [3]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [4]: 

In [4]: dom = minidom.parse(StringIO(x))

In [5]: Src = dom.getElementsByTagName('Src')

In [6]: output = ",".join([a.childNodes[0].nodeValue for node in Src for a in node.getElementsByTagName('Dir')])

In [7]: print(output)
C:\User1\test1,C:\User2\log,D:\Users\Checkup,D:\Work1,E:\job1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but using this I'm getting 5time the same line .. otherwise it fine...Pls help again..

Comment: Unless you are doing it i n a loop that loops five times you are definitely not seeing it five times use the code above. I added exactly what you get

Comment: Sorry, but how to load the xml dynamically in the python script, as in line 2:

Comment: In [2]: x = r"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Exactly as you were before, `minidom.parse('Test0001.xml')`

Comment: `dom = minidom.parse('Test0001.xml')`, that is it.

Comment: How do I get the same file output as: ['C:\\User1\\test1', 'C:\\User2\\log', 'D:\\Users\\Checkup', 'D:\\Work1', 'E:\\job1']